# Prevent HTML read-only text fields to be changed

Tags: javascript, html, grails, jqgrid, master-detail

I'm developing a Grails web application whose modules, mostly, must implement a master-detail interface. As an approach, I want to put the following code to your consideration:

**Master Class:**

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray

class MyForm {
    String name
    String address
    String detail
    BigDecimal total

    static hasMany = [details: MyFormDetail]

    static constraints = {
        name()
        address()
        detail()
        total()
    }

    static mapping = {
        detail type: 'text'
    }

    def beforeInsert = {
        def detailJSON = new JSONArray(detail)
        detailJSON.each {
            def quantity = it.getAt("quantity").toString().toBigDecimal()
            def description = it.getAt("description").toString()
            def unitaryPrice = it.getAt("unitaryPrice").toString().toBigDecimal()
            def subtotal = it.getAt("subtotal").toString().toBigDecimal()
            def myFormDetail = new MyFormDetail(
                    quantity: quantity,
                    description: description,
                    unitaryPrice: unitaryPrice,
                    subtotal: subtotal
            )
            this.addToDetails(myFormDetail)
        }
    }
}
```

**Detail Class:**

```
class MyFormDetail {
    Integer quantity
    String description
    BigDecimal unitaryPrice
    BigDecimal subtotal

    static belongsTo = [myForm: MyForm]

    static constraints = {
        quantity()
        description()
        unitaryPrice()
        subtotal()
    }
}
```

**myFormUtilities.js helper file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#detailTable").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 100,
        colNames: ["QUANTITY","DESCRIPTION","UNIT. PRICE","SUBTOTAL"],
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'quantity',index:'quantity', width:100},
            {name:'description',index:'description', width:400},
            {name:'unitaryPrice',index:'unitaryPrice', width:100},
            {name:'subtotal',index:'subtotal', width:100}],
        caption: "DETAIL"
    });

    createTable();

    $("#addRow").bind("click",addRow);
    $("#removeRow").bind("click",removeRow);

    $("#quantity, #unitaryPrice").bind("keyup",calculateTotal);

    function calculateTotal(){
        let quantity = parseFloat($("#quantity").val());
        let unitaryPrice = parseFloat($("#unitaryPrice").val());
        let subtotal = quantity*unitaryPrice;
        $("#subtotal").val(subtotal);
    }

    function addRow(){
        let row = new Object();
        row.quantity = $("#quantity").val();
        row.description = $("#description").val();
        row.unitaryPrice = $("#unitaryPrice").val();
        row.subtotal = $("#subtotal").val();
        let detailJSON = ($("#detail").val()=="")?"[]":$("#detail").val();
        let mydata = $.parseJSON(detailJSON);
        mydata.push(row);
        $("#detail").val(JSON.stringify(mydata));
        createTable();
    }

    function removeRow(){
        let filaId = parseInt($('#detailTable').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow')) - 1;
        let mydata = $.parseJSON($("#detail").val());
        let nuevoMydata = new Array();
        for(let i=0;i<mydata.length;i++){
            if(filaId!=i)
                nuevoMydata.push(mydata[i]);
        }
        $("#detail").val(JSON.stringify(nuevoMydata));
        createTable();
    }

    function createTable(){
        let total = 0;
        let aRow = new Object();
        let detailJSON = ($("#detail").val()=="")?"[]":$("#detail").val();
        let mydata = $.parseJSON(detailJSON);
        $("#detailTable").jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
        for(let i=0;i<mydata.length;i++){
            aRow = mydata[i];
            total += parseFloat(aRow.subtotal);
            $("#detailTable").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,aRow);
        }
        $("#total").val(total);
    }
});
```

This is the displayed form (I know it's an autogenerated view but see it as a very basic GUI mockup, please):
[image: master-detail mockup]

So, these are the issues:

- Both `Subtotal` and `Total` fields are calculated fields that were set
  `read-only` to prevent user to modify their content, but I found that
  using the browser element inspector their content and properties
  (like read-only) can be modified.
- Same happens with `detail`. If its content is altered, a server side
  error will be produced when the instance is saved because the `beforeInsert` block needs a valid
  JSON string to create the `detail` instances. This field is also used to generate the detail JqGrid. This field will be
  hidden.

Everything with this example is working as expected but a fault could be caused by a curious user.

- Is there a way to prevent these fields text to be changed even using
  the inspector?
- Is there another *place* to keep this data safe from alterations?
- I'm using this `detail` field to save a JSON string and this is my solution to implement the master-detail pattern. Is there another
  way to improve this implementation avoiding the need to define a
  field for this string?

Comment: So, if you don't want a user to edit a value, then don't accept changes to that value server side.  So, for example, Price... don't trust what comes from client side for the value of Price.  Only trust the value of Price server side (from your database). Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

If your users have access to the inspector/web console, then they have access to all the client-side data that you do (they are only limited by their knowledge of how to use the browser's dev tools). They can change any element's text or input's value. Thus, the only place that would be 100% safe to store this data is on the server side.

What you can try, which would at least make it a lot more work for them to update anything, and might prevent the change events calling the server, is to hide each input (with CSS for instance) and replace it in the visible HTML with a `<span>` element (or some other non-form element). Then make sure that whenever the `<input>` value is changed, you update the text of the corresponding span. Something like:

```
$("#subtotalSpan").html( $("#subtotal").val() );
```

added inside the calculateTotal function. If you want them to not even be able to edit the HTML of a span, you could go even further and draw the value to a `<canvas>` instead of a `<span>`. They won't be able to change text drawn into a canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no easy answer for protecting the data sent from the browser. Any user-submitted input should be treated as dirty by your server.

Data sent in a POST or GET can always be altered on the client side or even created wholesale (with something like CURL or Postman). For that reason, you should always validate the user input on the server side and compute your totals there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have properties that you don't want to participate in the mass property data binding you should configure them with `bindable: false`.

You have this:

```
class MyFormDetail {
    Integer quantity
    String description
    BigDecimal unitaryPrice
    BigDecimal subtotal

    static belongsTo = [myForm: MyForm]

    static constraints = {
        quantity()
        description()
        unitaryPrice()
        subtotal()
    }
}
```

You could change that to something like this:

```
class MyFormDetail {
    Integer quantity
    String description
    BigDecimal unitaryPrice
    BigDecimal subtotal

    static belongsTo = [myForm: MyForm]

    static constraints = {
        quantity()
        description()
        unitaryPrice bindable: false
        subtotal bindable: false
    }
}
```

If you have something like this:

```
MyFormDetail mfd = new MyFormDetail()
// The body of the request will be read and
// bound to mfd but subtotal and unitaryPrice
// will NOT be updated...
mfd.properties = request
```

If you do that, you can still assign values those properties directly:

```
mfd.subtotal = // ... some value here
```

Another option is to submit your form to a controller action which accepts a command object.  That CO could look like this...

```
class FormCommand {
    Integer quantity
    String description
}
```

If you have an action that looks like this:

```
class SomeController {
    def someAction(FormCommand co) {
        // it won't matter if subtotal
        // and unitaryPrice are in the
        // request, the co only has the
        // the properties you want so now
        // you can use those to update the
        // corresponding persistent entity
        // in a safe way
    }
}
```